# identifying pattern in datasets

Tags: classification, datasets, unsupervised-learning, autonomous-vehicles, supervised-learning

i am new to machine learning. i'm trying to identify driving pattern through accelerometer and gyroscope sensor. i have been collecting the data of both the sensors and have been storing them in .csv extension. i am not able to identify a pattern in the datasets since it has a lot of datas. i have three independent variables of accelerometer and with that i need to identify the sudden acceleration and sudden breaking and i have three independent variables of gyroscope and i need to identify aggressive turns. can you suggest as to how i need to analyse the pattern and find a algorithm which suits my requirement. this is how the dataset is

[image]

Comment: is your data sequential? does it have time? can you plot it on time scale?

Comment: yes,it does have time. The data table is as follows; time,speed,Ax,Ay,Az,Gx,Gy,Gz